# New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment Expansion

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory, powershell-cmdlet

I am creating a User and applying an app role that is in a custom application built in Azure using this cmdlet and it's running well. The thing is, I have multiple Azure custom built applications with the same role that I want the user to have in each. Is there a way of using this cmdlet and, let's say, set the -ResourceId to multiple ServicePrincipals to allow the ingestion of this user in each application all at once or will I have to do it one by one?

My current code:

```
$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = "<Password>"
$PasswordProfile.EnforceChangePasswordPolicy = $True
New-AzureADUser -DisplayName "<Display Name of User>" -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -UserPrincipalName "<developer's test user>@dosinvest.onmicrosoft.com" -AccountEnabled $true -MailNickName "<NickName to use for Mail name>"
$username = "<developer's test user>@dosinvest.onmicrosoft.com"
$app_name = "<Name of Application>"
$app_role_name = "<Display Name of Role within Application>"
$user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "$username"
$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$app_name'"
$appRole = $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $app_role_name }
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id
```

Comment: Thank you @robdy, I hadn't considered using `ForEach`. After adding this to my script it indeed worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ResourceID` parameter takes `String` as an input based on [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureaduserapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0) so it's not possible to give it multiple IDs.

What might help you is `ForEach`. For example let's define array of application names (notice **names** instead of name):

```
$app_names = "<Name of Application>","<Name of Application2>"
```

You basically need to iterate this array and run the cmdlets for each app from the list (this assumes that `$app_role_name` is the same for all of them):

```
$user = Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId "$username"
$app_role_name = "<Display Name of Role within Application>"

foreach ($n in $app_names) {
  $sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$n'"
  $appRole = $sp.AppRoles | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -eq $app_role_name }
  New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $user.ObjectId -PrincipalId $user.ObjectId -ResourceId $sp.ObjectId -Id $appRole.Id
}
```

Additional resources:

- [Basics of PowerShell Looping: Foreach](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/28/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/)